How can I see the number of files that the current folder contains, excluding the files located in subfolders, with ncdu?
I use ncdu to browse some folders. How can I see the number of files that the current folder will contain, excluding the files located in subfolders?

By default in ncdu, the number of files that the current folder contains includes the files located in subfolders:

I am aware of other commands, e.g. (author: Maja Piechotka):
 find . -maxdepth 1 -type f | wc -l

but I'd like to know if ncdu can do it.

ncdu <pathToScan> --exclude=<excludeDirA> --exclude=<excludeDirB> --exclude=<excludeDirC>

Example: sudo ncdu / --exclude=/dev --exclude=/Applications
For more options, here is the ncdu scan documentation:
 Scan Options

These options affect the scanning progress, and have no effect when 
importing directory information from a file.


-x  Do not cross filesystem boundaries, i.e. only count files and directories on the same filesystem as the
           directory being scanned.

   --exclude PATTERN
       Exclude files that match PATTERN. The files will still be displayed by default, but are not counted
       towards the disk usage statistics. This argument can be added multiple times to add more patterns.

   -X FILE, --exclude-from FILE
       Exclude files that match any pattern in FILE. Patterns should be separated by a newline.

   --exclude-caches
       Exclude directories containing CACHEDIR.TAG.  The directories will still be displayed, but not their
       content, and they are not counted towards the disk usage statistics.  See
       http://www.brynosaurus.com/cachedir/

   -L, --follow-symlinks
       Follow symlinks and count the size of the file they point to. As of ncdu 1.14, this option will not follow
       symlinks to directories and will count each symlinked file as a unique file (i.e. unlike how hard links
       are handled). This is subject to change in later versions.

source
man page
